# Spring data rest - expose default methods

Tags: spring-data-rest, default-method, spring-repositories

I have a Person Repository as follows

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, String> {
    List<Person> findAll();

    default List<Person> findNewPersons() {
         return findByStartDateAfter(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(3));
    }
    List<Person> findByStartDateAfter(LocalDate date);
}
```

I am not able to expose the default method through rest.. is there a way to do it without creating an implementation of the repo ?

Comment: findByStartDateAfter should be reachable via the search resource: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.search-resource

Comment: I am able to reach `findByStartDateAfter` , I am looking to access the `findNewPersons` (the default method)

Comment: @rathinakumar, did you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem, and was able to solve it using a SpEL expression inside an HQL query in a `@Query` annotation.

While nowhere near as clean as using a default method, this was the tidiest way I could find without writing a custom controller or introducing a custom implementation with a new DSL library or something for just this one query.

```
@Query("select p from Person p where p.startDate > :#{#T(java.time.LocalDate).now().minusMonths(3)}")
List<Person> findNewPersons();
```

My actual query was different so I might have typoed the syntax here, but the idea is the same and it worked for my case (I was using a `LocalDate` parameter and finding timestamps on that day by using a `findByTimestampBetween` style query).

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the specific case best solution is to write query method.

To expose method to REST via @RepositoryRestResource need to create your own inteface which your class annotated with @RepositoryRestResource extends and then write Impementation for that interface.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, String>, 
MyNewPersonRepository { ... } 

public interface MyNewPersonRepository { 
   Optional<Person> getNewPerson(); 
}

public MyNewPersonRepositoryImpl implements MyNewPersonRepository {
   @Override 
   Optional<Person> getNewPerson() {
      return ...; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class AppRepositoryConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {

        config.setExposeRepositoryMethodsByDefault(true);
    }
}
```